# Can I demo my Flex mobile app in a Flash player?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5, flash

How can I demo my mobile app on a web page? or standalone

Is there a way to show my Flex mobile app in a browser?  either on a web page or standalone is ok.

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 to build a mobile app for iOs (iphone 4) and when I debug it, it shows the program in a window like the phone,

Is there a way to wrap this up and give it to someone to run in a Flash-player-browser-like window?
So they can see it the same way I do when I debug the program?

thanks!

steve

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link that illustrates running a mobile app in the browser:
http://www.riagora.com/2011/08/flex-mobile-in-the-browser/